# How do I make an inline element take up space when empty?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have an h1 and h3 tag that will erase itself and type, using theater.js. The problem is that when it erases itself to empty, the height of the div it's in get smaller, then snaps bigger when it has content again.

I want to make the h1 and h3 tag (or change the tag completely) keep its height even while empty.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you post some codes or something that you have tried please

Comment: ...also headings are not inline elements...they are block level.

Answer (score 2):

Just wrap your h2/h3 tag in a div with `display: inline-block;` like this:

```
<div class="header2"><h2>ABCD</h2></div>
```

and then add this to your css:

```
    .header2 {
      min-width: 100px;
      width: auto;
      min-height:45px;
      background-color:#333;
      color:#FFF;
      display:inline-block;
      padding:10px;
    }
```

Here's a jsfiddle of two h2 tags with the above properties: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/21/

Comment: You can remove the min-width if that is unnecessary. I kept it there just to show that the button even the button width can be kept too

Comment: It would be better to use an `em` value rather than a fixed pixel one.

Comment: @Paulie_D Agreed but this fiddle is just for showing the way to go around adding a space to an empty header tag so I just kept some random pixels just for explanatory purposes :)

Comment: "Just"? There must be easier ways.

Comment: @DavidSpector lol what?

Answer (score 1):

two possible solutions:

**1) you can set min-height to the div**

For example:

```
div{min-height:50px;}
```

**2) or to set min-height of h2 and p1 tags**

h1,p1 {

```
min-height:5px;
```

}

**Demo for 2nd approach :**

```css
h1{
    background:yellow;
    min-height:5px;
}
```

```html
<h1></h1>
```

**Note**: as paulie_D mentioned, h1 ,p and div are block level elements by default

Comment: Well I didn't downvote but your answer does nothing to solve the underlying problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D he want that the div should retain its height even when the h1 and p are erased. so min-height will work. correct me if i am wrong

Comment: No...he want's the empty element to retain it's height, not the parent.

Comment: @Paulie_D what i read was { the height of the div "it's"  in get smaller...keep "its" height even while empty}.

Comment: you properly mean     .header2 {min-height:50px; }

Comment: @Paulie_D check the html he posted...there is nothing but the header inside this div

Comment: Check his last line...he want's the **heading** to retain it's height

Comment: @HatemAhmed the other answerer posted the code, paulie_d is right about the content of div

Comment: @Paulie_D you are right ^_^ yet the html contain only the H1

Comment: Sounds good, but how do you know the height of the H element under all browser conditions?

Answer (score 1):

You may use a pseudo element to force an empty space within the element and swip it away with `text-indent`

```css
h1.fixed:before {
  content:' ';
  display:inline-block;
  width:1em;
}
h1 {
  background:lightgray;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 1px;
  }
h1.fixed {
  text-indent:-0.8em; /* swip off the pseudo element */
  }
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true"></h1>
<h1 class="fixed" contenteditable="true"></h1>
```

else, use the :empty pseudo-class

```css
h1:empty:before {
  content:'|';
  }
```

```html
<h1 contenteditable="true"></h1>
```

Comment: I haven't seen this approach before. I'll try it out, and see if it work well.

Comment: @SimonS you can also use the :empty pseudo class to add some content, so it's never empty (see snippet up here)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of erasing the content of an H1 element, set it to `&nbsp;` . This is the entity that is rendered as a space. This should hide the element, but still take up the same vertical space as desired. Hopefully, it will not confuse screen readers (for blind users), either.