# Unloaded Heading Tag Causing Flicker

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code:

```
<div ng-cloak ng-init="viewAlbum()" class="ng-cloak">


<h3 ng-cloak class="ng-cloak" ng-bind="album.Title"></h3>    


<table ng-cloak class="ng-cloak">

    <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><span class="album-label">Composer</span></td>
        <td class="value-col">{{album.Composer}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><span class="album-label">Release Year</span></td>
        <td class="value-col">{{album.ReleaseYear}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><span class="album-label">Rating</span></td>
        <td class="value-col">{{album.Rating}}</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td class="label-col"><span class="album-label">Reviews</span></td>
        <td class="value-col">
            <ol>
                <li ng-repeat="review in album.Reviews">{{review.Text}}</li>
            </ol>
        </td>
    </tr>


</table>
```

The problem is that I am seeing a quick flicker when the page load. I'm am not seeing raw unprocessed angular code. Instead, the entire table flickers including the static text such as the labels.

I did some experimenting - when I remove the `H3` tag, I no longer see the flicker. So, I believe what is happening is the `H3` tag is initially rendered with no value and therefore takes up no vertical space. When the value of the album title is rendered, the table is pushed down, and it is this "pushing down" that is causing the flicker. My theory could be wrong however.

The ng-clock attributes don't mitigate this. I tried a verbose option of surrounding the `H3` tag in a container `DIV` and setting the height and min-height of that `DIV` in the css but that also isn't preventing the flicker.

As I said, if I remove the `H3` tag, there is no flicker. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Why you dont use ng-bind instead of string interpolation ?

Comment: I am using ng-bind in <H3>

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the below link you can  Just wrap your h2/h3 tag in a div with display: inline-block; like this:

`<div class="header2"><h3></h3></div>`

and then add this to your css:

`.header2 { min-width: 100px; width: auto; min-height:45px; background-color:#333; color:#FFF; display:inline-block; padding:10px; }`

Here's a jsfiddle of two h2 tags with the above properties: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/e0d8my79/21/

Check :[How do I make an inline element take up space when empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29186769/how-do-i-make-an-inline-element-take-up-space-when-empty)

I recommend you also to use ng-bind for all your doms and remove the ng-cloak too